# unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application .net 4.0 on XP Sp3

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, msbuild, windows-xp

I'm having a problem with a WPF application on Windows XP SP3 32bit. I have a large file (832mb) with deployable resources so Visual Studio 2010 cannot build it. So I have built my file using MSBUILD. I mention this because it may cause the problem I have encountered but I'm not sure.

I have a WPF application built with MSBUILD in Windows 7 64bit. I run the program in Windows 7 and the program works. When I try to run it in Windows XP it does not run. The application ran before I used MSBUILD. I have .NET 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0 installed. In the the config file I have put:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
```

The app has been written in .net 4.0. I have tried the exact build number in the project config file as well and this hasn't helped. Some people sorted it by installing Direct X and running with admin, which still does not work. All updates have been applied. I have re installed .net 4.0 several times. The client and Extended.

As mentioned above I have to build the file using MSBUILD. I tried building it in Visual Studio 2010 but there seems to be a known issue of building single files over a certain size. I need it this size as splitting the file won't do. I am wondering now if MSBUILD has something to do with this, the file is too big in XP or .net is not picking this application up for some reason. Other files with the same setup that have been built in Visual Studio seem to work. So maybe I'm missing some build options in MSBUILD. The build command I'm using is:

```
msbuild "D:\Projects\MyProject\MySolution.sln" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
```

I also added this into the command:

```
ToolsVersion:4.0
```

Also I run the program from the desktop.

The Exception is:

```
"MyProgram.exe - .NetException Error"
"Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application"
```

Also, is there any limit on a single file or process in Windows XP?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you get an exception on the XP machine? You could have a look in the windows event log why the program terminated.

Comment: @SvenG - Thanks, I'll have a look at the logs. I have added the exception to the question.

Comment: There is a limit, finding a contiguous chunk of virtual memory to fit the EXE gets dicey beyond ~650 megabytes on a 32-bit version of Windows.  Not nearly as much of an issue on the 64-bit version since there's double the virtual memory available.  I suspect this is the real reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try just using this instead:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
```

Comment: I tried this to no avail already. I've tried a few different variations of the XML. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  How much is free?  Maybe try a memory defragmentation tool?